# How can I use shell commands and interact with the Linux system underneath?

Tags: linux, shell

Android is based on Linux and has a Linux kernel underneath. Is there any way I can use shell commands and interact directly with the Linux system? E.g. A shell app that has access to the Linux system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is,

Check out the application `Better Terminal` or `Android Terminal Emulator` both are support from 1.5

Comment: Don't forget that as TheCottonSilk noted in their answer that you'll need busybox in order to access most of the usual Linux commands!

Answer (score 11):

If you have a wireless network set up I can recommend to connect via SSH. It allows you to access and fully manage your Android in a few minutes. 
For Linux or Putty users there is no difference to a standard terminal using SSH besides some specific Android commands. Moreover, some file managers such as Nautilus support the SSH protocol so you will have the flexibility of a shell and additionally the comfort for file operations using a graphical file manager. I liked SSH so much that I have written a small how-to for Android ([in German](http://www.osfight.de/2011/06/android-per-ssh-verwalten/)). I know, it might not fully apply to your question but can be considered while working with an additional computer and an Android phone.

[image]

An easy to use SSH server is [SSH Droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImJlcnNlcmtlci5hbmRyb2lkLmFwcHMuc3NoZHJvaWQiXQ..), available in the Google market.

Comment: Do you mean set up an SSH server on the phone? That may be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I installed SSHDroid in no time and it is definately less complicated than setting up the Android SDK / ADB shell (check my tut). If you are experienced with SSH you will appreciate it for accessing the phone.

Comment: Huh, I had no idea. I would read your tutorial, but I don't know German :-).

Comment: I am going to add an English translation in the near future.

Comment: How exactly does it work? Does the SSH connection go over the USB cable?

Comment: My setup at home consist of a router with wifi and a computer connected to it. My android phone is connected to the wifi as well. From the computer you can access the phone simply by using "ssh root@192.168.0.100" whereas 192.168.0.100 is the IP address of my phone. Thats it.    Connecting to your phone via USB / Bluetooth check out this question [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/can-i-connect-to-a-shell-from-a-pc-to-my-android-using-bluetooth-or-usb)

Answer (score 10):

Recently I had similar requirement, and I found '[busybox](http://www.busybox.net/)' utility. The terminal emulator apps are useful however those support very few commands. However 'busybox' gave me access to most of the generally used Linux commands.

[Here is](http://mycottonsilk.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/busybox-on-android/) how I used it.

Comment: Even if you used busybox, you still need a terminal emulator to actually run busybox on. They're complementary.

Comment: Yes, very true..I agree.

Answer (score 6):

The [Scripting Layer for Android](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) also includes a shell.