# Can I connect to a shell from a PC to my Android using bluetooth or USB?

Tags: bluetooth, usb, remote-control, shell

I want to run some commands on my rooted android phone. It is not very practical to interact with a shell using the touch screen, therefore I wanted to run a daemon on it and connect to it from a PC. I can't use the wifi connection for that because it is not working properly. I figured that it should be possible to do it via bluetooth or USB, but I could not find information on how to do it.

Is there any ready-to-use solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just use ADB over USB and run `adb shell`.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands

Answer (score 2):

Before you run adb you have to install the [developer kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk) and set up your SDK environment to detect your phone ([instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)). Then you'll be able to use the [android debug bridge, or adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands), as @Matthew_Read suggests.

Connect your USB cables, check for a dialog on your phone to allow it to be mounted, and then run `adb devices` from your computer to confirm that your phone really is talking to adb. From there you can use `adb shell` to launch a shell environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a app called Android Shell https://play.google.com/store/search?q=androidshell.io in Google Play. You can install it on your device and use the web UI (http://androidshell.io) to connect to the device and execute commands.

Disclaimer
- I am the author of this app

Comment: How would this work in the situation the OP describes, where WiFi is not a working option?