# What useful Android Shell commands do you know?

Tags: shell

There are questions pertaining to the use of the [Android Shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/285/how-can-i-use-shell-commands-and-interact-with-the-linux-system-underneath) or to finding a [documentation of the Shell commands](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-shell-commands) on Android. Since I haven't found anything convenient, I would like to use this thread to compile a list of "useful" Android commands. I am going to add commands as they are posted.

Comment: What defines "useful"? How will answers be bounded or evaluated?

Comment: That could be useful for everyday use while working with the terminal. I will turn this into a Wiki as soon as the 8 hours time limit has past...ppl will figure it out than :)

Answer (score 21):

### **App Management**

Use Android package manager **pm**

```
usage: pm [list|path|install|uninstall]
       pm list packages [-f]
       pm list permission-groups
       pm list permissions [-g] [-f] [-d] [-u] [GROUP]
       pm list instrumentation [-f] [TARGET-PACKAGE]
       pm list features
       pm path PACKAGE
       pm install [-l] [-r] [-t] [-i INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME] [-s] [-f] PATH
       pm uninstall [-k] PACKAGE
       pm enable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm disable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm setInstallLocation [0/auto] [1/internal] [2/external]
```

#### Examples

Install the package com.twitter.android-1.apk from the SD card

```
pm install /sdcard/com.twitter.android-1.apk
```

List installed packages that contain the term *twitter*

```
pm list packages | grep twitter
```

Show the install directory of the twitter package

```
pm path com.twitter.android
```

### **Processes**

```
top
```

Lists all running processes / apps with live updates showing CPU usage, PID,...

```
ps
```

Lists all running processes / apps and allows filtering using grep

#### Examples

```
ps | grep apps
```

Lists all running apps on your phone

### **Mounting**

```
mount -o rw,remount -t "filesystem" "Device" "Mount Point"
```

Allows you to remount your partitions for write access or to mount images.

#### Examples

Write access for the root filesystem

```
mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /
```

Write access for your /system partition

```
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system
```

Write access for /system using **busybox**

```
busybox mount -o remount,rw /system
```

Mount the contents of `myimage.img`, viewable in the folder `myimage`

```
mount -o loop /sdcard/myimage.img myimage
```

### **Other**

`getprop` can show interesting details from the device configuration, such as DNS servers, gateways, GSM details, running services, build parameters, version info etc.

Comment: `netcfg` is `ifconfig` for android..

Answer (score -1):

here is /system/bin
I haven't gone through yet to add documentation though, my apologies.
I have made a google doc where I and some friends plan to put our documentation over spring break. If people want to help out, it would be much appreciated. 
[Android Shell Commands](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XaCCyAf46_gQYUIWHyRSCQue6d-TzJmKOZ1z1cpl1sI/edit?usp=sharing/%22Android%20Shell%20Commands%22)

/system/bin contents:

> BasicHashtable_test
>
> BlobCache_test
>
> InputChannel_test
>
> InputDispatcher_test
>
> InputEvent_test
>
> InputPublisherAndConsumer_test
>
> InputReader_test
>
> Looper_test
>
> ObbFile_test
>
> String8_test
>
> Unicode_test
>
> Vector_test
>
> ZipFileRO_test
>
> adb
>
> am
>
> app_process
>
> applypatch
>
> applypatch_static
>
> asan
>
> asanwrapper
>
> atrace
>
> audioloop
>
> bmgr
>
> bootanimation
>
> bu
>
> bugreport
>
> cat
>
> check_prereq
>
> chmod
>
> chown
>
> cmp
>
> codec
>
> content
>
> corrupt_gdt_free_blocks
>
> dalvikvm
>
> date
>
> dd
>
> debuggerd
>
> decoder
>
> dexopt
>
> df
>
> dhcpcd
>
> dmesg
>
> drmserver
>
> dumpstate
>
> dumpsys
>
> flash_image
>
> fsck_msdos
>
> gdbjithelper
>
> gdbserver
>
> getevent
>
> getprop
>
> gzip
>
> hd
>
> id
>
> ifconfig
>
> iftop
>
> ime
>
> input
>
> insmod
>
> installd
>
> ioctl
>
> ionice
>
> ip6tables
>
> iptables
>
> keystore
>
> keystore_cli
>
> kill
>
> linker
>
> ln
>
> log
>
> logcat
>
> logwrapper
>
> ls
>
> lsmod
>
> lsof
>
> make_ext4fs
>
> md5
>
> mdnsd
>
> mediaserver
>
> mkdir
>
> mksh
>
> monkey
>
> mount
>
> mtpd
>
> mv
>
> nandread
>
> ndc
>
> netcfg
>
> netd
>
> netstat
>
> newfs_msdos
>
> notify
>
> ping
>
> ping6
>
> pm
>
> pppd
>
> printenv
>
> ps
>
> qemu-props
>
> qemud
>
> r
>
> racoon
>
> radiooptions
>
> reboot
>
> record
>
> recordvideo
>
> recovery
>
> renice
>
> requestsync
>
> rild
>
> rm
>
> rmdir
>
> rmmod
>
> route
>
> run-as
>
> schedtest
>
> schedtop
>
> screencap
>
> screenshot
>
> sdcard
>
> sendevent
>
> sensorservice
>
> service
>
> servicemanager
>
> set_ext4_err_bit
>
> setconsole
>
> setprop
>
> sf2
>
> sh
>
> showlease
>
> skia_test
>
> sleep
>
> smd
>
> stagefright
>
> start
>
> stop
>
> stream
>
> surfaceflinger
>
> svc
>
> sync
>
> system_server
>
> testid3
>
> toolbox
>
> top
>
> touch
>
> uiautomator
>
> uim-sysfs
>
> umount
>
> updater
>
> uptime
>   vdc
>   vmstat
>   vold
>   watchprops
>   wipe