# Disable Android Apps - Application Manager

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung, processes

Some apps in Application Manager are completely greyd out and cannot be disabled. Is there any way to override this?

Comment: Sure. If your device is rooted.

Comment: It is rooted, So what do i do?

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your device is rooted, you might want to check some tools which help you on this task. Examples include [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), which (next to Backup almost everything) can *freeze* apps (which is the same as "disabling" them), and [App Quarantine](http://www.appbrain.com/app/app-quarantine-root-freeze/com.ramdroid.appquarantine), which is even dedicated to this job.

The two are just examples, there are more "tool boxes" out there capable of the job in question.

Another way (not requiring extra apps) is utilizing ADB for this: `adb shell pm disable <package_name>` could be used to disable an app (see also [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/11066/16575)).