# Can I fix a bootloop for non available storage by mounting a SD card?

Tags: boot, storage

I was receiving an alert from Whatsapp saying that my storage went full, so I wanted to clean it up but this morning I saw my phone and it got stuck in the boot logo. The weird thing is it lets me to write the password (and then it freezes).

Someone in Facebook told me that was because my phone ran out of storage and tries to write some logs (and since it hasn't space it keeps trying)

Can I fix this problem mounting a SD card so the phone can write the logs? is there another solution (except doing a hard reset)?

It's a OWN FUN 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What useful Android Shell commands do you know?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11052/what-useful-android-shell-commands-do-you-know)

Comment: None of them worked, since I can't enable debugging option. Thanks anyway

Comment: flashing `boot.img` does not concern userdata you won't lose anything with this method (enable usb-debugging via modified `default.prop`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I can't enable the debugging option, I gave up and went to hard reset. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

try airplane mode or remove sim card and try to reach developer options/usb-debugging at least. then you can free up disk space from `adb shell`

another method is readback `boot.img` with SP Flash Tool, modify  it and flash it back to device

Comment: I couldn't reach developer options, since it stills getting stucked at the logo, and I can't flash it because I don't want to lose internal storage