# execute linux commands on android froyo

Tags: 2.2-froyo, linux, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use shell commands and interact with the Linux system underneath?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/285/how-can-i-use-shell-commands-and-interact-with-the-linux-system-underneath)

I want execute linux commands on my android (Froyo).

How can i do it? any idea?

Should I root for that or any applications for execute linux commands.

Answer (score 1):

[Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) might be what you're looking for :)

Comment: I use the same emulator. Works great.